# Calling custom cakephp controller method results in database error

Tags: cakephp

I've created a simple method in mo controller, like so:

```
public function getAddresses() {
    $addresses = $this->Adres->find('all');
    return $addresses;
}
```

When I call this in a controller, like so:

```
    $this->loadModel('Adres');
    $sponsors = $this->Adres->getAddresses();
```

I get this strange error:

```
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'getAddresses' at line 1

SQL Query: getAddresses
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That's because here you are calling the method on the model

```
$this->loadModel('Adres');
$sponsors = $this->Adres->getAddresses();
```

When you clearly stated in your first sentence that the method is on the *controller*. Move the method to the `Adres` model and you should be good!